# cloth simulation with wind

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation, subdivision-surface

so I have been working on cloth simulator added with wind , I m trying to play with the setting , basically I wanted the coat object to interact with the wind but whenever I do this the coat just split with many pieces? Is there anyway to make it stand still and only effected by the wind without splitting into pieces? thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: sorry for the late reply , here is the link to my file

Comment: I can't see the coat that you show in your image, there's a dress but you didn't give it a Cloth simulation, are you sure that this is the good file?

Comment: im really sorry my friend that was an accident file my bad here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V3WoGcjDal18M2htRznHVcgnPaB7z51s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No problem but this time your link asks for an authorization   ;)

Comment: a bit noob when it comes to one drive , its all done now , thanks in advance mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have plenty of overlapping vertices, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. Also in the *Physics > Cloth* panel, under *Collisions* enable *Self Collisions*. You may also want to simplify the topology, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to untriangulate then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide* (the topology is still not perfect though).